A256KW is an unknown
I was getting error when I was generating JWE token by using A256KW algorithm.here is the error message
Error :-

org.jose4j.lang.InvalidAlgorithmException: A256KW is an unknown,
unsupported or unavailable alg algorithm (not one of [RSA1_5,
RSA-OAEP, RSA-OAEP-256, dir, A128KW, ECDH-ES, ECDH-ES+A128KW,
PBES2-HS256+A128KW, A128GCMKW]).


So after going deep inside I coded some of the part and got the issue, here was this
I took version, vendor and provider
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
String vendor = System.getProperty("java.vendor");
String home = System.getProperty("java.home");
String providers = Arrays.toString(Security.getProviders());
LOGGER.info("Initializing jose4j (running with Java {} from {} at {} with {} security providers installed)...", version, vendor, home, providers);

Then I checked that AES256 is present during initialization of the plugin
WrappingKeyManagementAlgorithm wrappingKeyManagementAlgorithm = new AesKeyWrapManagementAlgorithm.Aes256();
wrappingKeyManagementAlgorithm.getAlgorithmIdentifier();
LOGGER.info("FOR WrappingKeyManagementAlgorithm"+wrappingKeyManagementAlgorithm.isAvailable());

Then again I checked with this code
AlgorithmFactoryFactory factoryFactorys = AlgorithmFactoryFactory.getInstance();
LOGGER.info("FOR JsonWebEncryption"+factoryFactorys.getJweKeyManagementAlgorithmFactory().isAvailable(KeyManagementAlgorithmIdentifiers.A256KW));

So I got to know that java version less than 1.8.0_265 doesn't support this and some of the oracle java with less version you can check with this code.

Why would you even still be using a Java 8 update 265? The current latest Java 8 is Java 8 update 421.

In our project this was the issue, we were not getting the issue first then we coded some code given in the example then found the issue then we upgraded
